# Normalization - Foreign key being repeated

Tags: database, foreign-key-relationship, database-normalization

When normalizing data is it acceptable to have a foreign key repeated in the same table?

e.g. A courier company has an orders form and a customers form, the order form would log what customer to pickup an item from (Customer_ID) and would also have a column for what customer it is being delivered to (also Customer_ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable; the two indexes will be maintained separately.  The two relationships can be used separately...

```
select item, name, address from orders inner join customers on orders.sender = customers.id where orders.id = 5;
select name, address from orders inner join customers on orders.recipient = customers.id where orders.id = 5;
```

or together (with care)

```
select item, name as sender_name, address as sender_address, recipients.name as as recipient_name, recipients.address as recipient_address from orders inner join customers on orders.sender = customers.id inner join customers as recipients on orders.recipient = recipients.id;
```

*Do* be careful with cascade deletes ;)